# Chrome does not load external JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This ain't no spam, the [actual website I'm working](http://www.kalevloterija.lv/) on (sorry, it's in Latvian).

The problem here is that there is a tracking script provided by AdForm, which Chrome does not want to load. Firefox loads it smoothly. Have not checked with other browsers though.

Since the script is external, I cannot think of a way to debug it.

Has anyone experienced such a problem with Chrome and how do I fix this?

The script is right before the closing `<head>` tag.

### Update

As Blender has suggested, I've tried removing the async parameter before, but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely have the AdBlock extension (or some similar one) installed. If I disable AdBlock the script loads just fine in Google Chrome. With it activated, the script gets blocked.

**Update**

The AdBlock extension (both the Google Chrome and Firefox versions) uses EasyList, which is a list of adserver domains. Any files loaded from these domains are getting blocked by the extension, and adform.net, the domain your external JS file resides on [is on the list](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt) (do a CTRL+F for it).

Comment: Indeed, it's the AdBlock that breaks it. Why so?

Comment: What do you mean why so? That's the whole point of the AdBlock extension, to block ads and tracking scripts. Respect your users by acepting that some of them don't want to be tracked, don't want to see banners, etc.

Comment: Have not experienced that AdBlock blocks tracking scripts, didn't know that's counted towards advertisments. Why don't they block GA then?

Comment: That's a valid question. I think it's because GA doesn't give any identifying information about users away. As per their [privacy policy](http://www.google.com/analytics/learn/privacy.html), your data isn't shared with GA account holders, while with other adservers and tracking scripts, you don't have that guarantee. This is not to say that you, as a user, cannot configure AdBlock to block GA too, EasyList is just the default list of filters, you can add as many custom ones as you like.

Comment: Oh, I just found this: [EasyPrivacy](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easyprivacy.txt). "[...] is an optional supplementary subscription that completely removes all forms of tracking from the internet". It apparently also includes GA.

Comment: I had same problem. My javascript is ViewAd.js